# Debug messages not being printed on the console

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to enable printing the debug messages on the console.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int test_hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In init\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}

static void test_hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s: In exit\n", __func__);
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

To get the Info messages on the console, i executed the following command: dmesg -n7

```
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7   4   1   7
```

When I load the module using insmod, i don't get any message on the terminal, while it is available when I type dmesg. What mistake i am making here.

Answer (score 1):

Messages from kernel are not printed on terminal (unless it's specified as console= in kernel cmdline). They are appended to kernel log, which exists in kernel. It's accessible to user space programs via device file `/dev/kmsg`. This file is read by `dmesg` command in order to print kernel log content on terminal.

Comment: what should be the value of console field in ubuntu machine running on VM

Comment: If you are using serial console (e.g. `virsh console`) then `console=ttyS0` should work fine.

Comment: No. I am not using serial console. I want messages to be displayed on terminal

Comment: By " terminal" you mean QEMU monitor? If yes, then, as it's regular VT, so you should use `console=tty0`.

Comment: The one we use after typing CTRL+ALT+T, did not work after adding console=tty0, my command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.6 root=UUID=c17d5f82-e020-4ded-a082-89fd7e54d893 ro find_preseed=/preseed.cfg auto noprompt priority=critical locale=en_US sysrq_always_enablde nokaslr console=tty0

Comment: Note: I am in graphical mode running startx

Comment: Oh, I see. So you have VM with graphical environment and you're using terminal emulator. It's based on pty which is created dynamically when new emulator is started, so I think it's not possible to redirect kernel console to terminal like that. But it you just want to monitor kernel log, you may want to open second terminal emulator window and run `dmesg -w` command. It will print any messages added to kernel log instantly.

Comment: There is no 'w' option for dmesg

Comment: That's strange, dmesg supports if for many years now. What version of dmesg / kernel are you using?